# Changing Object Types in Object Oriented Design

Tags: class, design-patterns, polymorphism, uml

I have two kinds of member and two type of payment calculation for them. In first design I used one class for both member types and two calculation method in it. I know that, this design is not good.

And then I tried another design with polymorphism. In this design I have 2 classes for both member types. It seems better but there is a problem about this design. I have to change status of members after create them(special to regular or regular to special). How can I do that in second diagram or is there any better approach for this?

[image]

Comment: To me sounds like a good candidate for "Bridge"  http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/bridge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see them as a member and a special member, it would be more natural and easy to create member as a base class, with its own calculatePayment, and special member as a derived class, with overridden calculatePayment.

So, you could address the same object as parent or as a child, according to the state and thus switch  the function.

If you like your construction (I like it, too), give these classes other names (MemberCommon and MemberSpecial) and base them both on the same class "member". This class will calculate as:

```
if (state.isEqualTo("special")) 
    return(((SpecialMember)this).calculate())
else
    return(((CommonMember)this).calculate())
```

But the most honest way, I think, is simply to calculate according to the state - make one class, two functions and switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you'd ideally like is:

- Two Subtypes, `Member` and `SpecialMember`, each with their own implementation of `calculatePayment()`, and
- The ability to migrate objects between those subtypes.

Your second solution covers the first point.  Unfortunately mainstream OO languages don't generally support type migration.  A couple of options to consider:

1. The [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).  Encapsulate each `calculatePayment` method in a strategy subtype; when creating a member, bind the appropriate strategy subtype according to the member type.  If you need to migrate the member instance, just re-bind to an instance of the other strategy.
2. Use your second design and implement `migrate()` as an operation in each subtype.  The implementation will actually delete the current instance and create an equivalent of the other subtype.

Which to use depends on a number of factors.  (1) has slightly more runtime overhead each time `calculatePayment()` is called.  But the member object's identity is immutable.  (2) has less runtime overhead in `calculatePayment()` but the object ID isn't immutable since you're actually deleting the instance and creating a new one.

hth.